# Navigating XSD and XML file with a common Java tool/api

Tags: java, xml, xpath, xsd

What is the best way to navigate XSD and XML file? I want to find if XSD and XML both have same elements above or below to an input element.
Is it possible XPath? If yes provide a good tutorial as I am not able to find any tutorial to navigate XSD using XPath.

Comment: Your question is not clear.  XSD is XML that describes the structure of XML.  An XSD file will look very different from the XML it describes, so navigating them in parallel is not meaningful.

Comment: @JimGarrison Actually I have a defined standard XSD and I am generating request XML based on the XSD but if order of element is not according to XSD, my interface system will not accept the request xml.That's why I have to compare order of elements between XSD and XSD.

Comment: You're going to have to post the XSD and XML and show how it differs from what you want.  Also include how you're generating the XML from the XSD.

Comment: How is your task different from a simple XML validation using an XSD?

Comment: Very much agree with @biziclop : you're doign validation, and if you want to be able to report validation errors, then your best bet is to select a parser and a parsing method, and then search in the parser documentation how validation errors are reported and can be handled programmaitically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Processing XML Schema documents at the source code level is not at all easy, because there are many different ways of writing the same schema - for example, using attribute groups, model groups, extensions and restrictions, etc etc. So unless you know you are dealing with a restricted subset of XSD, I wouldn't recommend it.

Xerces provides an API to access the "compiled" schema model, which might be one way forward. Saxon also provides an option to export the compiled schema model as XML, which is a lot easier to process than the raw XSD files if you want an XML-based representation.